# Kendo React TreeView CheckBox not working

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, treeview

Checking CheckBox inside TreeView is not working.

[image]

This is the code. Treeview with CheckBox nodes inside expansion panel.

```
<ExpansionPanel
          className='item-body-dropDownList'
          title={"Expension panel"}
          expanded={expanded === item.id}
          tabIndex={0}
          key={item.id}
          onAction={(event) => {
            setExpanded(event.expanded ? "" : item.id);
          }}
        >
          <Reveal>
            {expanded === item.id && (
              <ExpansionPanelContent>
                <TreeView
                data={processTreeViewItems(tree, {
                  check: check,
                })}
                checkboxes={true}
                onCheckChange={onCheckChange}
              />
              </ExpansionPanelContent>
            )}
          </Reveal>
        </ExpansionPanel>
```

Tree data

```
const tree = [
    
    {
      text: "Item1",
    },
    {
      text: "Item2",
    },
  ];
```

onCheckChange

```
const onCheckChange = (event) => {
          const settings = {
            singleMode,
            checkChildren,
            checkParents,
          };
          setCheck(handleTreeViewCheckChange(event, check, tree, settings));
        };
```

I tried to implement TreeView from this web cite https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/treeview/checkboxes/  but its not working.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. My global CSS was overriding background-color of the CheckBox, so I just changed the background-color.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

you can see sample implementation of TreeView from here - https://codesandbox.io/s/rpkns2?file=/app/main.jsx

And some more details of the code would help more to debug this issue.

for ex. the implementation of this method - onCheckChange
and also the components ExpansionPanel, Reveal, ExpansionPanelContent

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated my question. Expansion panel is simple component which has TreeView inside. Just checking CheckBox inside TreeView is not working.

Comment: @Simo, thanks. can you also please add the full code of <TreeView /> implementation so that I can see how and from where you are handling the states or are those handled by props? just updating the first code block with full file code would suffice.

Comment: I posted the answer above. Thank you for the help. That example worked just fine. Global CSS was overriding default background-color value of the CheckBox

Comment: good to know. you can give a upvote if my answer helped.